# WP REST API orderby meta_value

Tags: wordpress, rest

Need to be able to sort the results of a REST API custom post query by a meta value.

Having difficulty doing so.

I have made my post type available to the REST API and can order by the Date, Title, etc...

But when I try the Post Meta it doesn't work.

I have added the following code to try and enable the functionality but defaults to ordering by date.

```
function my_add_meta_vars ($current_vars) {
  $current_vars = array_merge ($current_vars, array('meta_key', 'meta_value'));
  return $current_vars;
}
add_filter ('query_vars', 'my_add_meta_vars');
add_filter ('rest_query_vars', 'my_add_meta_vars');
```

My REST API query is

```
mysite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/hh_equipment?filter[orderby]=meta_value_num&meta_key=equipment_price&order=desc
```

I have tried following the instructions [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/251037/wp-rest-api-order-posts-by-meta-value-acf) to no avail.

*Running WordPress 4.8 and tried testing on 4.7 to no avail*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer below method,
I modified the existing routes to add a new args entry which validates the `meta_key` values which are permitted. No need to modify the rest query vars this way either.

```
add_filter('rest_endpoints', function ($routes) {
    // I'm modifying multiple types here, you won't need the loop if you're just doing posts
    foreach (['some', 'types'] as $type) {
        if (!($route =& $routes['/wp/v2/' . $type])) {
            continue;
        }

        // Allow ordering by my meta value
        $route[0]['args']['orderby']['enum'][] = 'meta_value_num';

        // Allow only the meta keys that I want
        $route[0]['args']['meta_key'] = array(
            'description'       => 'The meta key to query.',
            'type'              => 'string',
            'enum'              => ['my_meta_key', 'another key'],
            'validate_callback' => 'rest_validate_request_arg',
        );
    }

    return $routes;
});
```

REF: https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API/issues/2308

Comment: also had to add this [link](https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API/issues/2308#issuecomment-265875108) to make it work. `$type = 'custom_post_type';
add_filter('rest_' . $type . '_query', function ($args, $request) {
     if ($key = $request->get_param('meta_key')) {
         $args['meta_key'] = $key;
     }
     return $args;
 }, 10, 2);`

Answer (score 9):

I've got it working with the `rest_' . $post_type . '_collection_params` filter and `rest_' . $post_type . '_query` filter like so (change $post_type to needed post type slug):

```
// Add meta your meta field to the allowed values of the REST API orderby parameter
add_filter(
    'rest_' . $post_type . '_collection_params',
    function( $params ) {
        $params['orderby']['enum'][] = 'YOUR_META_KEY';
        return $params;
    },
    10,
    1
);

// Manipulate query
add_filter(
    'rest_' . $post_type . '_query',
    function ( $args, $request ) {
        $order_by = $request->get_param( 'orderby' );
        if ( isset( $order_by ) && 'YOUR_META_KEY' === $order_by ) {
            $args['meta_key'] = $order_by;
            $args['orderby']  = 'meta_value'; // user 'meta_value_num' for numerical fields
        }
        return $args;
    },
    10,
    2
);
```

The first filter adds your meta field to the possible values of the `ordeby` parameters, as by default REST API supports only: author, date, id, include, modified, parent, relevance, slug, include_slugs, title (check the `ordeby` param in [the WP REST API handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/#arguments))

The second filter allows you to manipulate the query that returns the results when you have your meta key inside the `orderby`. Here we need to reset `orderby` to 'meta_value' or 'meta_value_num' (read more about this in [WP Query class description](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#custom-field-post-meta-parameters)) and set the meta key to your custom field key.